# How to make list attachment mandatory in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, attachment, custom-lists

Anyone knows how to make attachment compulsory to the SharePoint custom list?
We are using SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the UI / Admin to do this AFAIK.

This arcticle explains how to achieve it with jQuery [Link](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-list-attachment-technical-brief.aspx)

Edited to correct my previous answer, which on reflection only provided a part answer. The above link is the correct way to achieve this. It shows the mechanism to query the attachments details on the NewForm, ie: before the list item is created, which is the point at which the mandatory function can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below function as a script in a "Content Editor Web Part" or directly to the form via SharePoint designer. Obviously, this also requires jQuery.

```
function PreSaveAction(){ 

    var hasAttachment = false;

    //There are more then one fileupload inputs on the form
    //and one of them will always be blank
    $("input[name^='fileupload']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            hasAttachment = true;
        }
    });

    if (hasAttachment){
        return true; //OK to save
    }else{
        alert('An attachment is required!');
        return false; //Prevents user from saving
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Better Create a workflow

which will send a mail to last modified by + cc team lead

"if the current item has attachment = no" send mail

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't make the attachment mandatory. It only complains if the file is not attached upon list item creation.